# How would I write a TypeScript function that returns the same type as the argument?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a TypeScript function that accepts either an object with string keys or an array of objects with string keys, modifies the keys into camelcase, and then returns the new object or array. However, I can't seem to get the types to work correctly.

This is what I have so far:

```
function camelKeys(obj: object): object {
    const modifiedObject = {};
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        modifiedObject[camelCase(key)] = value;
    });

    return modifiedObject;
}

function camelcaseKeys<T extends object | object[]>(obj: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(camelKeys);
    }

    return camelKeys(obj);
}
```

However, I get the error that `Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'T'.` and `Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.`.

How can I adjust these functions so that it will correctly typecheck?

Comment: The type _should not_ be the same because you are modifying the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are *explicitly* changing the type of the object you pass in (`{foo: string}` to `{Foo: string}`, for example).

Even if it were possible to trick TypeScript into making it of the same type (which can probably only be done by a healthy sprinkle of `any`s), it's an extremely bad idea, because you will get errors in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems to solve:

1. Telling TypeScript that `camelKeys` accepts some object, and then returns an object with different keys but the same values.
2. Telling TypeScript that when `camelcaseKeys` receives an object, it returns an object, and when it gets an array, it returns an array.

The first problem is solved by using a mapped type.

```
declare function camelKeys<T extends object>(obj: T): SameValuesAs<T>
```

We put a constraint on `T` — it must extend `object`. However, the return value is not just any `object`, but one with the same values as `T`. The `SameValuesAs` helper could look like this:

```
type SameValuesAs<T extends object> = Record<string, T[keyof T]>;
```

The second problem can be solved by using overloads or conditional types.

```
declare function camelcaseKeys<T extends object>(obj: T[]): SameValuesAs<T>[];
declare function camelcaseKeys<T extends object>(obj: T): SameValuesAs<T>;
```